# How to remember current page position on reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML webpage and I want to remember the scroll position with a lot of information, when I want to open a div, the page refreshes, how can I let the page remember the current scroll position?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you could always write the current scroll position to localStorage, and then check if localStorage has anything set on page load, if so scroll to the position...

Comment: you can use php.
get current position save it in for example session and use it after reload page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_save_scroll() {
    // get scrolltop value
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    // make http get request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/my_reload_div', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // (3)
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        // push xhr.responseText to 'my_div' element
        // restore scrolltop
        window.scrollTo(0,top);
    }
}
```